# custom post type not getting archived?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I'm used the plugin More Types to create a custom post type (News). I'm also using the plugin Smart Archives Reloaded to have an archive of my custom post type.

The problem is when i click on a month which takes me to .com/2011/10 i just get a page not found.

I've also added the wordpress archive widget to the sidebar just to see if it shows any of my posts, which it doesn't. If i post a normal post (one that comes built in with wordpress) that show's in the archive widget and also clicking on the month shows a page with that post on it instead of a page not found.

In the More Types plugin i've set the post to archives yes.

Is it possible the posts aren't getting archived and that's why i'm getting a page not found, or is this two separate issues?

Thanks

Comment: What is your permalink structure?

Comment: In the permalink settings it's set to custom and just uses %postname%. In the more types plugin for the custom post type the permalink base is news.

Comment: You should check the Archives Reloaded plugin settings, I believe it's messing up the rewrites and the permalink structure.

Comment: The only settings that are in Archives Reloaded is what you want to display for the posts. i.e. the post name or the author of the posts. There's no permalink settings is Archives Reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a plugin called collapsing archives and it appears to be working with that. Maybe it was an issue with smart archives not working with custom post types, not really sure. It's working now though.